# How should I refactor my app correctly?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create an app with ability for user to log in via `Facebook`, `Twitter`, `Google`, and `LinkedIn`. I'm using a single `UIViewController` and adding more and more code to `viewDidLoad` method. At this point my controller looks awful and I would like to split the code between associated classes (one for `Facebook`, and so on). I even thought about using custom views for every social media login button...
What would be the right thing to do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect readers of your question will be able to do given this (lack of) information.

Comment: Sounds like some of that code needs to move into a model class - logging onto these is not a GUI related activity (obtaining logon credentials from the user is, but doing something with them is not).

Comment: I just created a pastebin . com /3x1cugDR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two things to split in your case.

1. Login with different networks. It purely depends on your UI. You might have a separate view (and corresponding class) for each network or a popup.
2. Split code by applying an architectural pattern (MVC, MVVM, VIPER, etc.)
   Here is a nice overview of them: 
   https://techblog.badoo.com/blog/2016/03/21/ios-architecture-patterns/

Additional change you should do is to introduce a separate bunch of classes to handle log in via social networks. Then in your view controller (or better in a View Model or somewhere else, depending on the design pattern you choose) you call `SocialNetworkService.authenticateWithTwitter(email:password)`

But remember, these classes have to know nothing about view controller.

I hope my answer gives you a hint in which direction to go.

Comment: Oh. Thanks! But what do you mean classes have to know nothing about vc?

Comment: They shouldn't have any code that references the view controller. They must be independent from it.

Comment: This is so confusing! Anyway, thanks. :)